# First log backup after FULL taking lots of space

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, backup, transaction-log

In the backups I'm doing in my database, the first LOG backup I do after the FULL backup is taking too much space, even more than the full backup.

For example:

```
4:50 AM:  FULL BACKUP  - .bak 7.2GB
6:30 AM:  LOG BACKUP   - .trn 9.3GB
7:00 AM:  LOG BACKUP   - .trn 2mb
7:30 AM:  LOG BACKUP   - .trn 150mb
8:00 AM:  LOG BACKUP   - .trn 1mb
8:30 AM:  LOG BACKUP   - .trn 50mb
```

Note that the first LOG backup is in GB, while the others are in MB.

What I'm doing is the following:

- 4:50 am:  (using multiple steps in the same job, not running all of them in parallel)

  1. Index optimize
  2. DB integrity check
  3. FULL backup
- 6:30am and every 30 minutes after that:

  - LOG backup

Also, another job called `PurgeOldImportData` is executed every hour and it deletes old information, but it's currently deleting very little information (if any).  In fact, it takes only 2 seconds to execute.

[image: Execution Log]

Can anyone tell me why is this happening? Besides the space it takes, it takes longer to do the `RESTORE`.  Thank you!

**UPDATE:**

I'm using Ola Hallengren's scripts for backup.  This is what each job/step does:

*JOB: DatabaseBackup - FULL*

1. IndexOptimize:   `[dbo].[IndexOptimize] @Databases = 'USER_DATABASES'`
2. Database Integrity Check:  `[dbo].[DatabaseIntegrityCheck] @Databases = 'USER_DATABASES'`
3. Full Backup:  `[dbo].[DatabaseBackup] @Databases = 'USER_DATABASES', @Directory = N'D:\SQLServer\Backups', @BackupType = 'FULL', @Verify = 'Y', @CleanupTime = 24, @CheckSum = 'Y'`
4. BackupToS3:  (executes a .bat which moves the file, does not touch the SQL Server)

*JOB: DatabaseBackup - LOG*

1. `[dbo].[DatabaseBackup] @Databases = 'USER_DATABASES', @Directory = N'D:\SQLServer\Backups', @BackupType = 'LOG', @Verify = 'Y', @CleanupTime = 24, @CheckSum = 'Y'`
2. BackupToS3:  (executes a .bat which moves the file, does not touch the SQL Server)

At night users run some import data files, but they are not running nothing that produces 9GB of changes AFAIK. Even more, the biggest data imports are not run from 4:50am to 6:30am.

Comment: Are you sure the full backup was completed before 6:30 AM?

Comment: @AaronBertrand forgot to include the screenshot. Take a look. The full index optimize, DB check and full backup takes 37'

Comment: @PJMahoney I've added more info.  Process-CT-Cube does not work in that database.

Comment: I'm afraid to ask but what does the log backup file size look like right before you take your full backup? O.o

Comment: @AliRazeghi all LOG backups are under 700mb. The one before the FULL backup was around 50mb the last couple days.  The one right after the FULL backup is 6-9GB

Comment: Wouldn't the LOG backup right after the IndexOptimize / Database Integrity Check / Full Backup contain the activity of at least the IndexOptimize step? Not sure if any log activity occurs during Database Integrity Check. Plus any other changes happening between 4:30 and 6:30.

Comment: @srutzky if that's happening I couldn't say why. If the IndexOptimize is being executed before the full backup, then the full backup should have those changes and the next log backup only the changes made after the full backup. I might be wrong though :)

Comment: Can you checkpoint and make a transaction log backup after the reindex job and before the full backup?  This will isolate the most likely cause of the issue to diagnose, per what I am seeing.

Comment: @DiegoJancic "the next log backup only the changes made after the full backup." That is not how LOG backups work ;-). Try what I suggest in my answer and you will see. FULL backups do include the transaction log activity, but they do not clear out the tran log or reset the oldest LSN.

Comment: Just note SQL Server defer's transaction log backups while the actual full backup is taking place but I'm not sure if that would have a major effect.  I think if you do a checkpoint and log backup after reindexing/dbcc you will catch the growth most likely.  Look at the time taken and size for both operations.  If they are on the same/similar subsystem that correlates to the size of the backups, as long as both have compression enabled/disabled.

Comment: You might also want to consider perhaps making adjustments to the index job parameters, etc. if confirmed this is what's causing the log activity to be so high and big. There may be some things to make this impact less if you can confirm what it is as the ROOT problem. Sure you can toss in more log backups between to make those smaller, but accumulated, without trying to optimize that you still would get the same large amount of transaction between those times but in more files versus just one something to check once you find the actual cause. Typical 700MB X 2 hour isn't 6-9GB... @DiegoJancic

Comment: @PJMahoney I totally hear ya, It's a question for OP and want to get more data and it should not be taken as an answer.  I want to show OP that his log activity from reindexing is causing a lot of activity, or if it isn't then he has a closer idea of where the issue is, or basically isolating the root cause.

Comment: Thank you guys.  I would not like to make those changes during the weekend as I don't want to have to fix it on a Sunday, but I'll test it next week. I wonder how should I tweak it if this is the cause (very likely as now I understand how it works). Doc from Ola Hellengren: https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html

Comment: Answering my last question :) http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/12/tweaking-defaults-ola-hallengrens-maintenance-scripts/

Comment: Oh no problem @PJMahoney, I see your posts often and I appreciate the extra eyes.  None taken, just wanted to clarify why I was asking just in case I didn't write it clearly for other users as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking a **FULL** backup won't clear out the transaction log entries (unless the database is in **SIMPLE** Recovery Model). So whatever changes take place between your last **LOG** backup before the **FULL** backup (@ 4:30 AM), and the first **LOG** backup once that process is over (@ 6:30 AM) would be included in that 6:30 AM **LOG** backup. That is a 2 hour span (you typically do a LOG backup every 30 minutes otherwise) in which you, at the very least, run index maintenance via the IndexOptimize stored procedure.

If you want to test this out, just temporarily disable both the "IndexOptimize" and "Database Integrity Check" steps (meaning, if you are using the CmdExec step type so it can call SQLCMD, just add `REM` to the beginning of the line in both steps). Let that run for one night and if I am right, it will be *very* obvious. Then, remove the `REM` from one of the two steps so that only one of them runs again (maybe start with the "Database Integrity Check" step) and let that run for one night and then you should see how much impact each of those first two steps has on that "first" **LOG** backup.

If the "Database Integrity Check" step is taking up more than a small portion of that **LOG** backup, then you might be able to split that initial backup into two (even if not an even 50/50) by doing a **LOG** backup after the "IndexOptimize" step. If all (or most) of the **LOG** backup size is from the "IndexOptimize" step, then maybe try to schedule a **LOG** backup for 4:36 AM to attempt to cut the resulting **LOG** backup in *approximately* half (given that you show that first step running for just under 14 minutes).

Comment: Thanks.  If that's the case (I'm going to test it during the week). What would be the solution to be able to do a IndexOptimize and now having the log backup be huge? I'm running LOG backups from 6:30am until 4:30am next day to avoid it running at the same time the FULL backup runs.  I'd appreciate if you can extend your answer and tell me how to configure/schedule it right. Thanks.

Comment: @DiegoJancic I did add a suggestion: add a LOG backup between the "IndexOptimize" and "Database Integrity Check" steps. If all of the LOG backup size is from "IndexOptimize", then maybe try to schedule a LOG backup for 4:36 AM to attempt to cut the resulting LOG backup in _approximately_ half.

Comment: Got it thanks.  I was wondering if it's possible to avoid having those huge LOG backups. Doing a LOG backup after the Index optimize would not avoid that but it would speed up restores since that last LOG will be most of the time not needed.

Comment: Might not be "needed" from a "state of the data" point of view, but I believe you are required to restore it so that you can have an unbroken chain between FULL / DIFF backup and the most recent LOG backup. As I added to my answer, try scheduling one or even two LOG backups during the IndexOptimize step. Maybe even do every 2 minutes to see if that works.

Comment: I haven't tried it but this query from [SqlServerCentral](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1154448-146-1.aspx), "DBCC SQLPERF (LOGSPACE)" , may tell you the approximate size of the transactions ready to be written to the log.  It could be run 1/minute or between critical steps.

Comment: @DiegoJancic Actually, it occurred to me that if you add a step in here to do a LOG backup _after_ the IndexMaintenance and _before_ the FULL backup, then not only will the initial LOG backup not contain that bloat, but neither will the FULL backup :-). And assuming that you don't keep the LOG backup once you have the FULL, then you will have just saved almost double that space, right? I guess only testing will show the true figures.

Comment: Thank you all.  That was the problem.  I've changed the Index Optimize to execute once a week only and with other parameters as described here: http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/12/tweaking-defaults-ola-hallengrens-maintenance-scripts/ Now the LOG took around 100mb the first day after change.